How to get DisplayCutout height for camera hole in emulator?
I am making a full screen application and encountered a situation where controls can be partially covered by camera cutout. This situation occurs in the emulator with last Google Pixel models. I couldn't check it on a physical device yet.
I have tried various ways to find out the size of the display cutout, but always got DisplayCutout equals null.
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a feature of the emulator that does not show the display cutout for camera hole on screen?
Here is an example of code inside the OnCreate function, with which I tried (unsuccessfully) to find out the size of DisplayCutout:
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    DisplayCutout cutout = insets.getDisplayCutout();
                    if (cutout != null)
                        Log.d("mytag", "left= " + cutout.getSafeInsetLeft());
                    else Log.d("mytag", "Cutout is null");
                }
                else Log.d("mytag", "Old API");
                return insets;
            }
        });

The log always informs that "Cutout is null".
I also tried another approach, making layoutInDisplayCutoutMode equal to LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER. But it didn't work, the camera cutout continued to cover the controls.
Please guide me on the right path.
